# Вывод значения функции лишь для первого символа, а не для всех

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка? Нужно строку закодировать используя азбуку Морзе. Составила словарь соотвествия символов. Но функция работает только для первого вводимого символа, следующие игнорируются.

```
MORSE_CODE_DICT = { 'A':'.-', 'B':'-...',
   'C':'-.-.', 'D':'-..', 'E':'.',
   'F':'..-.', 'G':'--.', 'H':'....',
   'I':'..', 'J':'.---', 'K':'-.-',
   'L':'.-..', 'M':'--', 'N':'-.',
   'O':'---', 'P':'.--.', 'Q':'--.-',
   'R':'.-.', 'S':'...', 'T':'-',
   'U':'..-', 'V':'...-', 'W':'.--',
   'X':'-..-', 'Y':'-.--', 'Z':'--..',
   '1':'.----', '2':'..---', '3':'...--',
   '4':'....-', '5':'.....', '6':'-....',
   '7':'--...', '8':'---..', '9':'----.',
   '0':'-----', ', ':'--..--', '.':'.-.-.-',
   '?':'..--..', '/':'-..-.', '-':'-....-',
   '(':'-.--.', ')':'-.--.-'
}
def encryption(message):
   my_cipher = ''
   for myletter in message:
      if myletter != ' ':
         my_cipher += MORSE_CODE_DICT[myletter] + ' '
      else:
         my_cipher += ' '
      return my_cipher
```

Comment: `return my_cipher` должен быть на 4 пробела левее.

Comment: `MORSE_CODE_DICT[myletter.upper()]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
MORSE_CODE_DICT = { 'A':'.-', 'B':'-...',
   'C':'-.-.', 'D':'-..', 'E':'.',
   'F':'..-.', 'G':'--.', 'H':'....',
   'I':'..', 'J':'.---', 'K':'-.-',
   'L':'.-..', 'M':'--', 'N':'-.',
   'O':'---', 'P':'.--.', 'Q':'--.-',
   'R':'.-.', 'S':'...', 'T':'-',
   'U':'..-', 'V':'...-', 'W':'.--',
   'X':'-..-', 'Y':'-.--', 'Z':'--..',
   '1':'.----', '2':'..---', '3':'...--',
   '4':'....-', '5':'.....', '6':'-....',
   '7':'--...', '8':'---..', '9':'----.',
   '0':'-----', ', ':'--..--', '.':'.-.-.-',
   '?':'..--..', '/':'-..-.', '-':'-....-',
   '(':'-.--.', ')':'-.--.-'
}

def encryption(message):
    return ' '.join(MORSE_CODE_DICT.get(symbol.upper(), '') for symbol in message if symbol != ' ')
#                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

А Ваш код должен выглядеть приблизительно так:

```py
def encryption(message):
    my_cipher = ''
    for myletter in message:
        if myletter != ' ':
            my_cipher += MORSE_CODE_DICT.get(myletter.upper(), '') + ' '
        else:
            my_cipher += ' '

    return my_cipher
```